# Displaying default text on variables that can be edited by the user on a C++ command-line program?

Tags: c++, variables, text, default

For instance, displaying something like this:

```
'Insert player name: StackUser'
```

Shows "**StackUser**" by default, but lets that piece of text be changed by the user if looking for a different name. This default text is pretty common on windowed programs, but I don't know if its even possible to do on a command-line based program.

Comment: Could you clarify your question, please? I'm having a hard time figuring out what you want. Is your question to insert a difference name than the default you specified? If so, will the user be inputting that information via the command-line, or will it come from somewhere else?

Comment: Of course, Ill explain it better with an example. Lets say that the programs objective is to load certain information about a person. You are asked to enter the person's name and it will show its information. But in order to easen the work, a name is written by deafult, which you can edit it, its just like the initial value of the variable. The user might press enter if thats the name he was looking for, or just rewrite it if not.

Comment: You can have this imnage as an example (http://i.imgur.com/9Mdateq.png). You can see that, when you access that function, a default naem is already there, but you are suposed to be able to change it. Maybe its plain impossible to do it, its pretty common on windowed programs though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional approach (going back to Fortran programs in the 1960s) was to do something like this, which works well on any type of console (even a print terminal):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main () {
    string nam = "StackUser";
    cout << "Enter your name (or press <Enter> for '" << nam << "'): ";
    string newname;
    getline(cin,newname);
    if (newname.length() > 0) {
        nam = newname;
    }
    cout << "Username is " << nam << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Having called this program `default`, it can now be run like this:

```
$ ./default
Enter your name (or press <Enter> for 'StackUser'):
Username is StackUser

$ ./default
Enter your name (or press <Enter> for 'StackUser'): Simon
Username is Simon
```

If you want the user to be able to move the cursor back over the default text and edit it, the way to do that will depend on the particular environment in which you're working (e.g. the particular console or console emulator). In Unix you can use the `curses` library to do this on almost any terminal supported by the Unix system (exceptions include print terminals, for instance), but that won't work for a C++ program running in (say) the Windows command line. However, the number of keystrokes required to move the cursor back to the right point to edit the default text would be more than the number required to type the replacement, so having the user type the replacement is the sensible choice, I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, that works great and I agree it seems the most optimal way to do it. Sorry for the delay, but this is definitely Accepted! I wish I could upvote but not enough reputation yet.